# Find any mention of google in all files and subdirectories?

Tags: windows, findstr

I've tried various versions of this command, hoping to get a hit.  I put a blank txt document/file that only contained the string "google" and ran commands like this:

`findstr /S "google" ./`
`findstr /S "*google*" ./`
`findstr /S ".google." .\`
`findstr /S /C:"google" c:\my\directory`

What I'm thinking is I might need to have pipe an output format?

Please, tell me, in general, what am I doing wrong and how can I do this properly?

Comment: could you please remove the `powershell` tag as this question is not related to any Powershell code? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to mention the file in which you have to search the string.

Eg:

```
findstr /S "google" test_file.txt
```

To search in all files in a folder, add `*`.

Eg:

```
findstr /S "google" ./*
```

Answer (score 0):

The PowerShell way for this could be:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path 'D:\Test' -File -Recurse | 
    Select-String -Pattern 'google' -SimpleMatch | 
    Select-Object Path, LineNumber, Line  # properties you want returned
```

This would return

> ```
> Path                          LineNumber Line            
> ----                          ---------- ----            
> D:\Test\SomeOtherTextFile.txt          6 google          
> D:\Test\test.txt                       1 google          
> D:\Test\Blah\blah.txt                  3 find stuff with Google
> ```

Comment: Nice work.  I'm just curious, given your first rev. I've never been able to get Select-String to recurse on it's own. Is that correct?

Comment: @Steven Yes that is why I changed to use Get-ChildItem. While testing without, recursion didn't work and gives access denied exceptions..

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Well, you tagged this question **PowerShell**, so I assumed you know how to run a PS script. Simply copy this code in the PowerShell Editor (ISE) and hit the `F5` button on the keyboard or click the green 'Play' button.

Comment: @Theo Thank you.  Yes, I'm very excited about PowerShell scripting, but I have not had the amazing opportunity to learn much of anything about it so-far.  I'm going to get started right now, just to show you some respect.  Thank you very much for your posts! ♥

Comment: @Wolfpack'08 Ah, I see. Well, in that case, keep watching this site because there is so much to learn. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Regarding findstr I'd add /i to force case insensitivity.  It shouldn't need any output redirection purely to work, it'll just output in the screen.  /s will search the current directory and all sub directories.  If you specify a directory it will search that directory and all sub-directories:

```
findstr /i /s "google" .\*
```

The "*" seems to be required.

```
findstr /i /s "google" c:\temp\*
```

I did some testing before posting and it seems if you don't spec the "*" it just runs forever.

Regarding the redirection of the output my first instinct was to use or ">>" to redirect stderr and append into a file. However, it doesn't seem to respect line endings! The output runs together as a single line.

With pure PowerShell, you can use `Get-ChildItem` with `Select-String` & `Out-File` instead.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File | 
Select-String -pattern "google" | 
Out-File c:\temp\select-String-test.txt -Append
```

If you are starting your search at the root of c:\ you are bound to get some bloody red access denied errors.  Generally I don't care about those files, so I'll throw in `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue`.

Comment: Steven, You know it searches all of the encoded files and gets weird results.

Comment: **Recommended: add extensions to prevent Unicode Glyph results**: `findstr /i /s "google" .\*.php`

Comment: I presume "encoded" means Unicode not ASCII.  findstr isn't compatible with Unicode.  Unless there's a compelling reason not to, you should use PowerShell.  I'd have thought you were aware of the folder contents.  I'm not sure the extension will be a sufficient guard against the encoding issue.  Find.exe is Unicode compatible, but not as flexible and output is cumbersome. Failing that there are thousands of Windows Grep ports you could download and use.  I haven't done that in a long time because PowerShell can usually match whatever functionality is needed.

Comment: Thanks, @Steven.  I'll look into that to confirm.  I got an error message, as far as I remember, it said "flood of unrecognized Unicode Glyphs".